# What is the difference between FLASHBACK and AS OF TIMESTAMP?

Tags: sql, oracle, recovery

I wonder what is the difference between FLASHBACK and AS OF TIMESTAMP(like a condition in a select) as I can use both of this to recover some data?
Flashback seems a little bit more restrictive.

Thank you!

Comment: Add [link to documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/flashback.html) for reference

Comment: [flashback_**query**_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2112818): Specify AS OF **to retrieve the single version of the rows** returned by the query at a particular change number (SCN) or timestamp. [FLASHBACK TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01802): Use the FLASHBACK TABLE statement **to restore an earlier state of a table** in the event of human or application error.

Comment: There are three levels of flashback: query, table and database. Use whichever one you need.